# Converting a group element to an ordered list of generators in GAP

Tags: gap, computer-algebra-systems

Consider the free group on {a,b} which is gap is constructed with FreeGroup("a","b"). I want to cyclically reduce words. For example, given word $a^{-1}*b*a$, this would be achieved by conjugating by $a$. However, no matter how hard I try/read about GAP, I can not figure out how to have GAP detect that the first letter in the word $a^{-1}*b*a$ is $a^{-1}$. I assume this is because GAP views $a^{-1}*b*a$ as a group element (for which the notion of letter is meaningless) and not as a tuple $(a^{-1},b,a)$. But surely there is a way to generate such a tuple in GAP given a word in the free group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Subword(word,from,to)` to extract partial word expression, and `Length` to get the word length. (Be aware that if it is not a free group, but a finitely presented group, you need to use `UnderlyingElement` first, to get the free group word representing the element of the finitely presented group.)

Thus to get the list of generators, you would use: `List([1..Length(w)],i->Subword(w,i,i));`